# Catching the Arguments a program is called with

Tags: windows

I am facing the problem that we have a tool which needs a usbtongle to unlock.

As there is a bug in the current release it is somehow possible to call the program with a specific argument to start it without the keycheck.

This call is issued by a different tool.

So if you start the program with a button located within the menu of the "different tool" it is possible to start without the key.

So here is my question: Is it somehow possible on a Windows PC to get the arguments the program is called with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be multiple ways of doing it (taken from https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program)

1. Use the Program "[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)" and hover over the Process.
2. Call following in the command prompt

`WMIC path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline`

3. (Win 8) Task Manager -> Details -> Right Click on any Column and select "Select Columns" -> Select "Command Line"